# Calculate moving average of meteorological data for third dimension

Tags: matlab, moving-average

I am using global meteorological data. The data represents longitude x latitude x time steps. I want to calculate the moving average of five days for all latitude and longitude.

The image below shows the data structure. How can I make a loop to define the length of the moving window?

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a loop, consider using the [`convn`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/convn.html) function where you specify the average filter in the third dimension.  What you can do is define a window size... say 5 for instance, then use `convn` to give you what the average output would be.  You can also define what to do when the window goes over non-valid data.  To simplify, we can specify that the output shape is the same as the input, so you'd specify the `'same'` flag.  What this means is that for the first (n - 1) / 2 time observations, this is finding the average with zero padded elements, so it's up to you on how observe those, but for those elements that are valid within the observation window, you can interpret those as the average calculated over adjacent time steps within each latitude and longitude.

You haven't given us much, but assuming the input matrix is stored in `A`, simply do:

```
A = ...; % Define A here
n = 5; % Define window size
B = permute(ones(n, 1) / n, [3 2 1]); % Define filter
C = convn(A, B, 'same'); % Perform average
```

The reason why [`permute`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) was used is to transform the average filter that is a column vector of `1 / n` where `n` is your window size into a 3D singleton column so we can use this to filter in the third dimension.  The output `C` contains the averaged results.